# Retrieve variable from another in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I would like to retrieve the variable from another variable that just been set.

```
- set_fact:
    app_env: "{{ app_env | default('prod') }}"
    app_url: "{{ app_global_var_urls[ {{ app_env }} }}"

- name: "Check facts"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ app_env }} {{ app_url }}"
```

I tried out  below methods

`{{ app_global_var_urls[ {{ app_env }} }}`

`{{ app_global_var_urls.app_env }} }}`

`{{ app_global_var_urls.[ {{ app_env }} ]}}`

Is that possible to retrieve from another variable while setting ?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems.

First, you never nest Jinja template markers (`{{...}}`). If you're already inside a Jinja template context, just refer to variables by name.

Second, the variable you create using `set_fact` aren't available until after the `set_fact` tasks has finished running. In other words, within a `set_fact` task you can't refer to variables that you're creating as part of that task.

You'll need to rewrite your playbook to use two separate `set_fact` tasks:

```
- set_fact:
    app_env: "{{ app_env | default('prod') }}"

- set_fact:
    app_url: "{{ app_global_var_urls[ app_env ] }}"
```

Or do something like this:

```
- set_fact:
    app_env: "{{ app_env | default('prod') }}"
    app_url: "{{ app_global_var_urls[app_env | default('prod')] }}"
```